# jagged array of integers with different dimensionals in each entry

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

[I want to do something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kUXg.png) 
The array itself needs to be a single dimensional array but it's elements must hold different multidimensional arrays

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to do?  Please read [ask] and then [edit] in the specific example into this question, as opposed to a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
int[][,] array = new[]
{
    new int[2, 2],
    new int[3, 3],
    new int[4, 4]
};

foreach (var table in array)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
            table[i, j] = i * j; // feed in some value
}
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) (loop up `jaggedArray4` example).

---

You could consider not working with raw arrays, but encapsulate the matrices into a separate class. This way your code will be more readable.

Comment: Mate don't really know that much about jagged arrays but wouldn't it create an array with 2 dimensional context because of the  the "[,]"?

Comment: @BilalMalik: The array declaration syntax is quite strange in C#. This actually creates array (`[]`) of two-dimensional arrays (`[,]`).

Comment: but i need an array that has 2x2 ,3x3 and 4x4 respectively as it's elements?

Comment: @BilalMalik: That’s exactly what you get